# Loop crossing over itself

Tags: mesh

Im trying to make a cutout in a ring but I keep having the problem that the loops cut over themself at some point near the edge...
[image]

Comment: ...and the question is..? answers could be a) change topology or b) use a different way. About b), if you're using loop cut (ctrl-r), try knife tool instead.

Comment: Another solution would be to hide a part of your object before applying loopcut. But this will create ngons.